# HELP : SOQL Syntax error

Tags: trigger

I would like to filter on a different value:
`If Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\' and Etape = \'Perdu\ or Etape=\'Annule\' or Etape=\'emise\'')`;

My code:

```
RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.new,
 'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c', 'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\' and Etape__c <> \'Perdue\ or Etape__c <> \'Annule\' or Etape__c <> \'emise\'');
```

I have this error:

> Invalid string literal 'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\' and Etape__c <> \'Perdue\ or Etape__c <> \'Annule\' or Etape__c <> \'emise\''. Illegal character sequence '\ ' in string literal. à la ligne 36 colonne 50

THE TRIGGER:

```
Trigger MissionrollupAffairesFormation on Affaire__c (after delete, after insert, after update, 
    after undelete) 
{
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUnDelete){
        /**** POPULATE LISTS D'AFFAIRE ****/

        List<Affaire__c> AffaireFormation = new List<Affaire__c>();

        for(Affaire__c r : trigger.new) {
            if(r.Type_d_affaire__c == 'Formation') {
                AffaireFormation.add(r);
            }            
        }

        /**** POPULATE LISTS D'AFFAIRE ****/
        if(AffaireFormation.size() > 0) {
            //Cumul de montants d'affaire Formation gagnée test 
            List<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions = 
                new List<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
                    new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('SUM', 'Montant__c', 'Formations_vendues__c'),
                    new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c', 'Nbre_de_Formations_vendues__c')
                };

            RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.new,
                'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c', 
                'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\' and Etape__c = \'Gagnée\'');
        }

        //Cumul de montants d'affaire Formation en cours 
        if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUnDelete){
            List<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions = 
                new List<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
                    new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('SUM', 'Montant__c', 'Formation_en_cours__c'),
                    new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c', 'Nbre_de_Formations_en_cours__c')
                };

            RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.new,
                'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c', 
                'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\'  and Etape__c <>\'Offre à émettre\' or Etape__c =\'Offre émise\' or Etape__c = \'Négociation\' or Etape__c =\'Gagnée à priori\'')
        }

        //Cumul des affaires de type Formation total
        if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUnDelete){
            List<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions = 
                new List<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
                    new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c', 'Nbre_Affaires_Formation__c')
                };

            RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.new,
                'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c','and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\'');
        }

        // FIN DES CREATION, UPDATE, RECUP
        // Cumul des effacements d'affaires Dossier gagnées

        if(trigger.isDelete){
            /**** POPULATE LISTS D'AFFAIRE EFFACEMENT****/
            List<Affaire__c> AffaireFormationd = new List<Affaire__c>();

            for(Affaire__c r : trigger.old) {
                if(r.Type_d_affaire__c == 'Formation') {
                    AffaireFormationd.add(r);
                }            
            }
        }

        if(AffaireFormation.size() > 0) {
            // Idem qu'au dessus si effacement Formation vendues
            List<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions = 
                new List<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
                    new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('SUM', 'Montant__c', 'Formations_vendues__c'),
                    new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c', 'Nbre_de_Formations_vendues__c')
                };

            RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.old,
                'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c',
                'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\' and Etape__c = \'Gagnée\'');
        }

        // Idem qu'au dessus si effacement Formation en cours
        if(trigger.isDelete){
            List<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions = 
                new List<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
                    new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('SUM', 'Montant__c', 'Formation_en_cours__c'),
                    new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c', 'Nbre_Affaires_Formation__c')
                };

            RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.old,
                'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c',
                'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\' and Etape__c <> \'Gagnée\'');
        }

        // Idem qu'au dessus si effacement nbre de Formation 
        if(trigger.isDelete){
            List<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions = 
                new List<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
                    new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c', 'Nbre_Affaires_Formation__c')
                };

                RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.old,
                    'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c',
                    'Mission__c', 'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\'');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dahan -- this problem is emminently debuggable by displaying the value of the 6th argument once you enter rollupTrigger() method - this way you can see if all your escapes are correct and you can also copy/paste the result into DeveloperConsole or SFDC Workbench to verify the SOQL

Answer (score 3):

You haven't escaped your string properly:

```
and Etape__c <> \'Perdue\
```

replace with

```
and Etape__c <> \'Perdue\'
```

you've forgotten the single quote here

Comment: yes Thank you. I've forgotten it. It work but when I save the record I have this error message: Le déclencheur Apex MissionrollupAffairesFormation a provoqué une exception inattendue. Contactez l'administrateur : MissionrollupAffairesFormation: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: unexpected token: or: Class.RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger: line 50, column 1

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code from the trigger?

Comment: I've found the solution with <> until =